# First non-negative element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have an array that looks like:

```
hrarray = [-9,-7,0,3,7,8]
```

I've been trying to work out a function that selects the first non-negative (inc. 0) number in the array and returns the index (var elemid):

```
for (var i = 0, len=hrArray.length; i<len; i++) {
var num = hrArray[i];
if(num > 0) {
var elemid = i; //returns first non-negative element index
}
else if(num < 0) {}
```

Is my code logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you returning anything.

You can get the first non-negative with a single line:

```
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len && arr[i] < 0; i++);
```

Basically, we place the check for negatives in the for-loop guard. It will break once it finds a non-negative and hence return `i` of that first non-negative.

**Update #1 (to use in a function):**

```
function getFirstNonNegative(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len && arr[i] < 0; i++);
  // Use a ternary operator
  return (i === len) ? -1 : i; // If i === len then the entire array is negative
}
```

Comment: great - if I want to feed this so then I can get the corresponding another array (called list) can I call this as list[getFirstNegative(arr)] ?

Comment: Yep - just make sure you stick that in a function. Check my update.

Comment: Your update #2 gets the *last* nonnegative element, not the first.

Comment: @Mac Yeah I was too hasty with that one haha. Good catch :D Bummer for a second I really thought it was better :/

Comment: What does this function return in the event no negative numbers are found?

Comment: Are you searching for the first negative or the first non-negative? This function returns the index of the first non-negative. If no non-negative numbers are found (all the numbers are negative), it returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you're not breaking out of the loop once you find a non-negative value. This can be done with a [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement, or if you want to exit a function immediately, a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

The function should look a bit like this:

```
function findNonNegative(arry) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(arry[i] >= 0)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Note that this method returns `-1` if no non-negative elements are found.

And with a little tweaking, this can be shortened to:

```
function findNonNegative(arry) {
    for (var i = 0; arry[i] < 0; i++);
    return i < arry.length ? i : -1;
}
```

This version takes advantage of the behavior of the `for` loop to both test our values inside the loop and break out once a desired value is found. It also depends on the fact that `x < y` always returns false if `x` is `undefined`, thus ensuring we do not end up with an infinite loop. The last conditional expression is there to make the return value equal `-1` if no non-negative elements were found; that can be reduced to just `return i;` if you are okay with the return value being `arry.length` in that case.

Comment: Nice! You did the single for-loop as well. I guess the `length` check is unnecessary since x < y is false when x is undefined :D

Comment: @linstantnoodles Correct. It eventually stops after testing `arr[i]` when `i == length`, which in most programming languages would result in an out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will assign to elemid the last non-negative in the array. Try this:

```
var elemid=-1; // elemid should be declared outside the for statement
for (var i = 0, len=hrArray.length; i<len; i++) {
    if(hrArray[i] > 0) {
        elemid = i; //returns first non-negative element index
        break;
    }
}
```